# how to create 3 columns landscape layout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i'm fighting with 3 columns landscape layout

i would like to print a page with 3 same fix with columns (unfortunately height are not the same, sometimes pages will break down to 2 pages)

what i would like to get in landscape is:

[image]

and what i'm getting is:

[image]

i cannot position this like it should be

can you advise me for some good solution for this crap please

any advice will be helpful, or maybe you whose already struggling with this problem and you can give my god direction please

i who's doing this not in landscape a few days ago and it whose working find

i didn't find a solution in web for this now

this is my starting code:

```
 <?php
include("bd.php");

$print[] = null;

if(isset($_GET['option1'])) {
    $print = $_GET['option1'];
}

$integerIDs = array_map('intval', explode(',', $print));
$usersIDS = implode(',', $integerIDs);
$requete = "SELECT p.pr_id as id, p.pr_nom as nom, p.pr_poids as poids, p.pr_ingredients as ingredients, p.pr_description as description, p.pr_valeurs_energetiques as valeurs_energetiques, p.pr_valeurs_nutritionnelles as valeurs_nutritionnelles, c.ca_nom as categorie, sc.sc_nom as sous_categorie, p.pr_enligne as enligne FROM produit p,categorie c,sous_categorie sc WHERE p.pr_id_categorie=c.ca_id AND p.pr_id_sous_categorie=sc.sc_id AND p.pr_id IN ({$usersIDS})  ORDER BY p.pr_id";

$resultat = mysql_query($requete);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($resultat);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="fr">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" media="print" href="css/print.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" >
        /* PAGE SETTINGS */
        .pageRotate
        {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
        }
        .rowMainPage {


        }
        .column {
            width: 63mm;
            border: solid #000000 1px;
            float: left;
            position:relative;
            padding: 0;
        }
        /*PAGE ITEMS*/
        .logoPuricard{
            width: 7em;
            top: 0;
            margin-left: 38%;
            margin-bottom: 5px;

        }
        /*PRODUCT IMAGE*/
        .productImg {
            width: 8em;
            float: left
        }
        /*PRODUCT NAME*/
        .nom {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-left: 2em;
        }
        /*Product weight*/
        .weight {
            margin-left: 4em !important;
        }
        /*Product description*/
        .ProductDescription {

        }
        /*Product container of small peaces(Ingrédients,Valeurs énergétiques etc..) with black border*/
        .divSmallContainer {
            border: solid 1px #000000;
            width: 100%;
            /*margin-left: -1em;*/
        }
        /*Container for valor energetic*/
        .valeurEnergContainer {
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body class="pageRotate" onload="window.print()">
<!--CONTAINER START-->
<div class="container">
    <?php
    if($num_rows > 0) {
    /*
  Start with variables to help with row creation;
*/
    $startRow = true;
    $postCounter = 0;

    $idCheck = 0;

    while($num_rows > 0){
    $ligne = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultat);

    if ($startRow) {
        /*LOGO  START*/
        echo  "<img class='logoPuricard' src='./images/logo.jpg'>";
        /*LOGO  END*/
       /*PAGE ROW START*/
        echo '<div class="row rowMainPage">';
//        /*FIRST COLUMN START*/
//        echo   '<div class="col-md-12">';
        echo "<!--    TEST 6 kolumn        -->";
        $startRow = false;
    }
    $postCounter += 1;
    ?>
    <?php
    $id = $ligne["id"];
    $nom = $ligne["nom"];
    $poids = $ligne["poids"];
    $ingredients = $ligne['ingredients'];
    $description = $ligne['description'];
    $valeurs_energetiques = $ligne['valeurs_energetiques'];
    $valeurs_nutritionnelles = $ligne['valeurs_nutritionnelles'];
    ?>

    <!-- FIRST COLUMN START   -->
    <div class="col-md-4 column"  >

<!-- Product IMG START   -->
    <?php if (file_exists('../Assets/produit_'.$id . ".png")) {?>
        <img class="productImg" src="../Assets/produit_<?php echo $id; ?>.png"  />
    <?php  } ?>
<!-- Product IMG END   -->

<!-- Product NOM START   -->
<?php if(isset($nom) && !empty($nom)){
    echo "<p class='nom'>". utf8_decode($nom) ."</p><br>";
}?>
<!-- Product NOM END   -->
<!-- Product WEIGHT START   -->
<?php if(isset($poids) && !empty($poids)){
    echo "<p class='weight'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Environ". utf8_decode($poids) . "g"  ."</p><br>";
}?>
<!-- Product WEIGHT END   -->
<!-- Product DESCRIPTION START   -->
<?php if(isset($description) && !empty($description)){
    echo "<p class='ProductDescription'>". utf8_decode($description)  ."</p><br>";
}?>
<!-- Product DESCRIPTION END   -->

<!-- Product INGREDIENT START   -->
<?php if( $ingredients){
    echo"<div class='divSmallContainer'>";
    echo"<b style='text-decoration: underline;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Ingrédients :</b><br><br>";
    echo "<div class='valeurEnergContainer'> $valeurs_energetiques; </div>";
    echo"</div>";
}

?>

<!-- Product INGREDIENT END   -->



<?php

    if($postCounter != 3 || $postCounter != 0) {
        echo '</div>'; /*END OF COLUMN*/
    }
    if ( 3 === $postCounter ) {
        echo ' </div>'; /*END OF COLUMN*/
        echo '</div><!-- PAGE ROW END-->';
        $startRow = true;
        $postCounter = 0;
//            echo "<span class='breakPage'></span>"; //add page break
    }


    --$num_rows;
    }/*endWhile*/

    if ($postCounter !== 0 ) {
        echo '</div>';
    }

    }else {
        echo '<div class="page-header"><h1>Pas des resultat</h1></div>';
        echo ' <p>desole vous n\'avez pas choisir des produits</p>';
    }

    if ( 3 === $postCounter || $num_rows == 0 ) {
        echo '</div><!-- END OF INTERNAL ROW -->';
        $startRow = true;
        $postCounter = 0;
    }

?>


<!--CONTAINER END-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to rotate the page, as this will do just that - rotate EVERYTHING. Just put all the CSS you want for your landscape print layout under the `@media print{@page {size: landscape}}` media query.

Comment: I think you slightly misunderstood me, I was saying that his code `rotate(-90deg)` will rotate everything. I probably could have worded that better.